# Visual C++ member variables changing unexpectedly and unexplainably

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I'm initializing an instance of PhysWorld class as shown here:

[image]

At this point the member variables are as follows:

[image]

This seems correct to me.

Then this line executes:

[image]

We step into:

[image]

And at this point, the member variables look like:

[image]

Can someone please help me understand what is going on here?  This is one of my first attempts in c++ so I'm guessing it's something stupid on my part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably loose variable value on assignment:

```
pw = PhysWorld(...);
```

This statement constructs a temporary object, and then makes a call: `pw.operator=(const PhysWorld&);`. Check how you implement it (if you do).

Also your function `setRectDef` contains a serious bug: you are storing a pointer to a stack variable, which would be invalid after leaving the function scope, and accessing it later most likely ruin your stack.

Edit: how to handle `tmpS`.

You need to allocate your structure on heap:

```
b2PolygoinShapre *tmpS = new b2PolygoinShape;
tmpS->SetAsTextBox(...);
this->rect = tmpS;
```

Comment: Ok this is why I didn't want to use c++, what do you mean storing a pointer to a stack variable?  I think &tmpS means the pointer to tmpS but I'm assigning it to the member variable which is supposed to be a pointer.  Why will accessing it later ruin my stack?  I'm sorry but I have very little experience with c++

Comment: @Mason `tmpS` is allocated on stack. And you are storing pointer to it into `this->rect`. After you leave the function scope the `tmpS` object will be destroyed. So you are left with a pointer to some area in a stack, that can be used by your program... And attempt to use is as a pointer to `b2PolygoinShape` type would cause many intersting, yet unwanted, results.

Comment: ok, could you please let me know what the correct method would look like?  I now understand that tmpS no longer exists but I'm unsure how to make it stick around.

Comment: @Mason using `operator new` will help your cause. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ok, I think I understand now.  I was told not to use the new keyword because then I would have to call delete on everything I use new for.  I think I tool that advice out of context because I think this is the only way to do some things.  However, just to be clear, anything I use new on needs to be deleted manually correct?

Comment: @Mason Generally yes (with some exceptions you can learn later). It is not difficult to handle in this case: just in `PhysWorld` destructor call `delete rect`. If `rect` is `null`, it will silently pass, otherwise will release the object.

Comment: Thank you so much Valeri, you have been a big help!